# Replace an object by another object in the same frame in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a list with to options on the homepage (index.html). The problem I am encountering is that when I run the code; if the user clicks on "list_row1" then "table1" shows up (everything works great), and after this if the user clicks on "list_row2" then "table2" shows up 100-200px below table1 (everything does not work great). I want table1 to simply be replaced by table2 and vice-versa in the same spot by the list (list_row1 and list_row2) option the person clicks on.

For example, I want a red circle to be replace by a black circle and vice versa..

Here is my `index.html` with `JavaScript` code below:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#list_row1').on('click',function(){
    $('#table2').hide();
    $('#table1').toggle();
  });

  $('#list_row2').on('click',function(){
    $('#table1').hide();
    $('#table2').toggle();
  });                     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <div id = "list_row1">
      <li class="list-group-item">Exhaust Temperature</li>
    </div>
    <div id = "list_row2">
      <li class="list-group-item">Cylinder Pressure</li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id = "table1"></div>
<div id = "table1"></div>
```

Comment: Do you really have two divs with `id="table1"`? You do in your question.

Comment: you can't use a div as direct child of a list

Comment: Why are you using `toggle` rather than `show`?

Comment: This was an mistake I made when copying the source code to here, sorry. I am using toggle because I can click to open and click to close. Actually hide(), should not be necessary in this case. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

Please check your code. you have two divs with same id

```
<div id = "table1"></div>
<div id = "table1"></div>
```

Comment: Mistake I did when copying the source code to here.

Answer (score 1):

Your id is same for both the tables. this should be your code:-

```
<div>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <div id = "list_row1">
      <li class="list-group-item">Exhaust Temperature</li>
    </div>
    <div id = "list_row2">
      <li class="list-group-item">Cylinder Pressure</li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id = "table1">table1</div>
<div id = "table2">table2</div>
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('#list_row1').on('click',function(){
      $('#table2').hide();
      $('#table1').toggle();
    });

    $('#list_row2').on('click',function(){
      $('#table1').hide();
      $('#table2').toggle();
    });                     
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi its a typo both of your table have same id 'table1'. And also a small suggestion hide both the table divs at the load itself. I'm posting the new JavaScript code below have a look.

```
$(function(){
  $('#table2').hide();
  $('#table1').hide();
  $('#list_row1').on('click',function(){
    $('#table2').hide();
    $('#table1').toggle();
  });

  $('#list_row2').on('click',function(){
    $('#table1').hide();
    $('#table2').toggle();
  });                     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you could toggle the two 'table' divs while also improving your markup: http://jsfiddle.net/8fr0484L/3/

Use `<a>` anchor tags inside your `<li>` list items instead of attempting to use divs. This will allow you to make use of the anchor tag's default clickable behaviour.

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href='#' id='list_row1'>Exhaust Temperature</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href='#' id='list_row2'>Cylinder Pressure</a></li>
</ul>
```

In the code it might be worth hiding the 'table' divs in the beginning (on page load), assuming you don't know at that point what the user wants to view.

```
        // hide the tables by default when page loads
        $('#table1').hide();
        $('#table2').hide();

        $('#list_row1').on('click',function(event){
            event.preventDefault(); // halt the anchor tag's default behaviour
            $('#table2').hide();
            $('#table1').show();
        });

        $('#list_row2').on('click',function(event){
            event.preventDefault(); // halt the anchor tag's default behaviour
            $('#table1').hide();
            $('#table2').show();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <div id = "list_row1"><li class="list-group-item">Exhaust Temperature</li></div>
    <div id = "list_row2"><li class="list-group-item">Cylinder Pressure</li></div>
</ul>
</div>

<div id = "table1">abc</div>
<div id = "table2">pqr</div>

<script>
$(function(){
    $('#list_row1').on('click',function(){
        $('#table2').css({
            visibility : "hidden"
        }); 
        $('#table1').css({
            visibility : "visible"
        });
    });

    $('#list_row2').on('click',function(){
         $('#table1').css({
             visibility : "hidden"
         }); 
         $('#table2').css({
             visibility : "visible"
         });
    });                     
});
</script>
```